# Re-publishing content from an expired domain to a new one

Tags: google-search, google-ranking

I had a tech blog for years but due to lack of time I let it expire in Jan this year. However I had some great content on it and I want to put all those articles back online under a new domain since the old one has been bought by someone else.

How do you think Google will react? Will I get ranked or banned as having duplicate content though the old domain, owned by someone else now, has different content published on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be fine from Google's perspective. Content that migrates from one domain to another is a common enough use case. As you note, the content is no longer available under the original domain, so you should be clear.

When doing to migration, it can be a good idea to upgrade whatever template or coding you use to be consistent with current html5 and responsive design practices. If the content is good enough to put back online, make it accessible!